# Column change that affected other columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following table:

```
$table->boolean('prop_enabled');
$table->boolean('prop1_enabled')->nullable();
$table->boolean('prop2_enabled')->nullable();
$table->boolean('prop3_enabled')->nullable();
```

My requirement is when `prop_enabled` is `false`, then `prop1_enabled`, `prop2_enabled` and `prop3_enabled` values shall be set to `null` during row insertion or update.

Is my table design is appropriate for solving the problem?
If my table is good to solve the problem, which approach is better to handle my requirement? I have options to create trigger on database, or to override `Create` and `save` method from `Model` class.

Comment: you wouldn't need to override those methods, models have events you can listen for, like the `saving` event

Comment: Thank you @lagbox, If I use event listener will there be 2 queries for each create? 1st for creating the row, 2nd query for updating new row based on prop_enabled column

Comment: no ... `saving` is before the model is saved

Comment: you could also just ignore the other fields no matter their values in the database when `prop_enabled` is false with mutator. Wich will be less heavy on the performance and avoid issues linked to mass assignement and model bypass insertion/update methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best approach is doing the Observer solution. Using an mutator, requires a lot of mutators to secure your data structure and / or business logic that can ignore it. The observer is using events and there for you can only circumvent it from triggering by avoiding using eloquent.

You can hook into the `saving` event on Models. This will look at the model before saving it, then alter it, if your case is true and thereby creating the optimal 1 query insertion. No matter how your business logic is, this will trigger before the creation or updating.

```
class YourModelObserver {
    public function saving(YourModel $model) {
        if ($model->prop_enabled === false) {
            $model->prop1_enabled = false;
            $model->prop2_enabled = false;
            $model->prop3_enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In a provider you have to register your listener.

```
public function boot()
{
    YourModel::observe(YourModelObserver::class);
}
```

My biggest problem with your design is a common code smell i have seen before. Naming variables after numbers, when you have multiple just seems wrong for me. What happens if you get the 4. prop and how will you handle showing them and updating em? An alternative approach would be to have em in a more generic fashion in another table when they had a name or key instead of being prop1 or prop2 and having logic associated with creating them or updating em. If you are certain the prop1, prop2 and prop3 are not gonna change the design is good for now.

Comment: Thank you @mrhn for your support and your comment on the code smell. I just want to make the property more generic, I would not use this naming on the project.

Comment: Fyi in the current project im on, they had person1, person2 and person3 properties and it has created so much pain that it was designed like that.